# Panels cache terminology- what's the difference between caching by argument vs. by context?

Tags: panels, caching

I'm trying to learn how to set up Panels caching.  I watched a video on [mastering Drupal caching](http://barcelona2012.drupaldays.org/sessions/mastering-drupal-cache) and I have the book by Earl Miles on Panels and Views, *Drupal's Building Blocks*, but unfortunately there's not a chapter specifically on caching.

So, I have a panel that overrides the user profile, and on this panel I have a variant that has a number of views content panes.  I would like to cache these content panes per user profile displayed, since obviously they should be different for each user who is viewed.

Each of these content panes has a **Contextual filter** on *Content: Author UID*.

The value is supplied to Panels by the *Argument input* option in Views, for which the **Content: Author uid source** is set to *From context* and **Required context** is set to *User ID*:

[image: views screenshot]

In Panels, on the **Simple cache** configuration screen, for the **Granularity**, I can choose *Argument* or *Context*, and the help text is this:

> If "arguments" are selected, this content will be cached per
>   individual argument to the entire display; if "contexts" are selected,
>   this content will be cached per unique context in the pane or display;
>   if "neither" there will be only one cache for this pane.

But in Views, the option is called *argument input* and the value I chose was *from context*.  So am I dealing with an argument or a context?

If possible, both a general answer describing the difference between argument and context in this case and a specific answer to my question would be fantastic.

Comment: Posted an answer, hopefully it answers both the generic question and your situation, but let me know if I didn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclaimer: I usually find that the setup is simple enough that the distinction isn't necessary, thus I must admit my practical experience is limited, and I could be wrong below.

`Arguments`, are based on the URL. `node/5` gets cached separately from `node/7`, because 5 is different from 7. `node/5/7`, if you where to have such a path, is yet another cache.

`Contexts`, are generally derived from `Arguments`, and in the examples above, it's very likely that the caches would be exactly the same, regardless of which cache option one would pick. However, `Contexts`, can also come from (at least) three other sources, `Relationships`, manually defined ones, and the special case, the logged in user.

If your context is both a node from the URL, and a user pulled from an `entity reference` on the node, then your context has two unique entities, or two contexts, but only one argument.

So one chooses `Context` or `Argument` depending on whether you want the cache to take any "extra" contexts into question, or not.

> But in Views, the option is called argument input and the value I chose was from context. So am I dealing with an argument or a context?

Unfortunately the terminology isn't exactly the same between the two modules. Panels calls dynamic pieces of the URL arguments, and it creates contexts from those. Views, means something closer to a function argument, when it refers to arguments, and in this particular case, it will derive the argument from a context, passed in by Panels.

Comment: So, say, if I want the cache to take into account both the *logged in user* and the *user being viewed*, I should use *Contexts* not *Arguments*?

Comment: Yes, if you use Arguments in that situation, _logged in user_ would be ignored.

Comment: I added that to the list of context sources.